# take someone down a peg vs. cut someone down to size?

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-usage

Which phrase is more common in English? "To take someone down a peg" or "to cut someone down to size"?
I know they both are used in English to mean "to show someone that they are not as important as they thought", but I'm wondering how they are different in usage.

Comment: It looks like 'cut him down to size', but not by much. [Google 5-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+him+down+a+peg%2Ccut+him+down+to+size&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20him%20down%20a%20peg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccut%20him%20down%20to%20size%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctake%20him%20down%20a%20peg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccut%20him%20down%20to%20size%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: N-grams only measure print references. These are speech idioms and thus would normally occur thousands or millions of times more often than any printed and counted reference would ever note. If they're close in printed references, they're equally part of the language and neither can be preferred to the other. They're both the same metaphor theme, just different measurement variations.

Comment: They're both relatively common idioms.  They have slightly different meanings.

Comment: To add to the comment by @HotLicks above, the difference in connotation between these two expressions strikes me as one of degree--"cutting someone down to size" strikes me as being more aggressive than merely "taking someone down a peg."

Comment: As JohnLawler alludes,  if the person thinks they are bigger than they really are, then they can be cut down to size, if they think they are higher (or above others) then they can be taken down a  peg.